# In apples "displaying data in a list" swift ui tutorial I have the same code as the example with a different result

Tags: swift, swiftui

I copy pasted each line of code and still have different results then what is shown online.

I then downloaded Apple's completed project example and it ran properly.

How could the same code being copy and pasted not work but when just downloaded it worked fine?

I am trying to learn but I have been stuck on this for hours, I even put my code in a comparer and they are the exact same.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ScrumsView: View {
    let scrums: [DailyScrum]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(scrums) { scrum in
                NavigationLink(destination: Text(scrum.title)) {
                CardView(scrum: scrum)
            }
                .listRowBackground(scrum.theme.mainColor)
        }
    }
        .navigationTitle("Daily Scrums")
}
}

struct ScrumsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
        ScrumsView(scrums: DailyScrum.sampleData)
    }
}
}
```

Theme code, it is not adding a folder with the colors atm

```
enum Theme: String {
    case bubblegum
    case buttercup
    case indigo
    case lavender
    case magenta
    case navy
    case orange
    case oxblood
    case periwinkle
    case poppy
    case purple
    case seafoam
    case sky
    case tan
    case teal
    case yellow
    
    var accentColor: Color {
        switch self {
        case .bubblegum, .buttercup, .lavender, .orange, .periwinkle, .poppy, .seafoam, .sky, .tan, .teal, .yellow: return .black
        case .indigo, .magenta, .navy, .oxblood, .purple: return .white
        }
    }
    var mainColor: Color {
        Color(rawValue)
    }
    var name: String {
        rawValue.capitalized
    }
}
```

Comment: show the code **you** have, and the errors you get, so we can have a look and help you.

Comment: added some text, the full example of what I am doing can be seen here. https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/displaying-data-in-a-list the colors just aren't changing from the base of white but all the text is the same

Comment: good start with the code, however you haven't described what is not "working" or what errors you get.

Comment: So basically it is supposed to look like the first image but it is the second image https://imgur.com/a/rDRWE8t this is a different part of the code but same thing. My question is, is there factors other the the text that would effect why the colors aren't lining up? The text is identical on all "pages" of the code everything has been copy pasted between the known good one and the broken one and it still doesn't work. I'm lost as to what it could be as again the text and layout is identical as well as the emulator.

Comment: can you show what you call `the first image`? The code you show in the question certainly does not match the picture you show.

Comment: the first image in the imgur link I sent code is here https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/creating-a-navigation-hierarchy

Comment: @Boaztheostrich, I'm having some trouble understanding Your question. Best i  can understand from image shown by you is that there are problem with color showing in apple code and color not showing in code you created exactly same. But i think check for colors in assets.

Comment: @NamraParmar omg ur so right the one I downloaded has colors in the themes, a theme folder was never created when I ran the code how do I do that??

Comment: @Boaztheostrich, glad you found the problem. :)

Comment: @NamraParmar any idea how to go ahead and add colors into the themes folder? I added my theme code to the question

Comment: @NamraParmar nmnm "The starter project includes the asset catalog and defines the RGBA values for each color." I was supposed to download that at the start lol thx

Comment: @Boaztheostrich, You have to manually add each color in assets with exact same name. It is the only way as far as i know.

Answer (score 0):

Check Assets/Themes, in the Apple tutorial there is a folder containing all colour sets from the Theme enum.
Without all colour sets your list will have white background.